# Reversing numbers with leading zeros

Tags: java, integer

I want to write a program that reverses a number (without converting it to a string). I have my code working for all numbers except numbers with leading zeros, for example: `500` and numbers like that. It simply gives me `5` when I want `005`.

Here is my code

```
System.out.println("Enter a number with at most 10 digits:");
            long inputNumber = myKeyboard.nextLong();
            long tempInputNumber = inputNumber;
            long reversedNumber = 0;
            int digits = 0;
            int rightMostDigit;

            while(tempInputNumber != 0) {
                rightMostDigit = (int)tempInputNumber % 10;
                reversedNumber = (reversedNumber*10)+rightMostDigit;
                tempInputNumber = tempInputNumber / 10;
                digits++;
            }
```

Comment: Numbers do not have leading zeros in Java. You **need** a `String`. Best of luck.

Comment: The `long` type represents whole numbers within a certain range.  It doesn't represent how many leading zeroes you want in the output.  So there's no difference between a `long` of 5 and a `long` of 005.

Answer (score 0):

What if you stored each digit as a number in an array, like they do for one-hot encoding?